# How can I query a table that will allow for multiple filters on a calculated field in a dashboard?

Tags: sql, nosql, google-bigquery, dashboard

A little bit of background first:

I am working on a project for work and am really stumped on this. I have a relatively small dataset for now that consists of roughly 1,000 records that are all responses from people who took a survey.

For this particular case, I am trying to calculate a number called NPS (Net Promoter Score) which is based on the individual giving a "score" of 0-10 to the product they own. You then take the percentage of people who give the product a 9 or 10 (Promoters) and subtract from that the percentage of people who gave the product a 0-6 (Detractors). It is very basic math.

So the formula looks like this: **% Promoters - % Detractors = NPS**

Now comes the part where things get more complicated. Using other responses in the survey I would like to be able to filter this NPS score based on their groupings from these other responses. For the purpose of this post we will keep it to three: "Consumer Segment" (We'll call them S1, S2, S3, S4, S5), Gender (M or F), and Generation (Gen Z, Millennial, Gen X, Baby Boomer+).

I have been able to get this to work with one filter, which you will see below in my code. The trouble is allowing for multiple filters at the same time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  Dataset1.NewTable1 AS
SELECT
  DISTINCT Segment,
  SUM(Promotor) - SUM(Detractor) AS Net_Promotor_Diff,
  SUM(S1_count) AS S1_Count,
  SUM(S2_count) AS S2_Count,
  SUM(S3_count) AS S3_Count,
  SUM(S4_count) AS S4_Count,
  SUM(S5_count) AS S5_Count,
  SUM(S1_count) + SUM(S2_count) + SUM(S3_count) + SUM(S4_count) + SUM(S5_count) AS Total_Count
FROM (
  SELECT
    ResponseId,
    Segment_column AS Segment,
    IF (SAFE_CAST(NPS_Score AS Int64) > 8, 1, 0) AS Promotor,
    IF (SAFE_CAST(NPS_Score AS Int64) < 7, 1, 0) AS Detractor,
    IF (SAFE_CAST(NPS_Score AS Int64) IN (7, 8), 1, 0) AS Neutral,
    IF (Segment_column = 'Segment 1', 1, 0) AS S1_Count,
    IF (Segment_column = 'Segment 2', 1, 0) AS S2_Count,
    IF (Segment_column = 'Segment 3', 1, 0) AS S3_Count,
    IF (Segment_column = 'Segment 4', 1, 0) AS S4_Count,
    IF (Segment_column = 'Segment 5', 1, 0) AS S5_Count
  FROM
    Dataset1.MainTable
  WHERE
    Segment_column IS NOT NULL )
GROUP BY
  Segment
```

This query results in the following table. I have shortened the column names to allow the table to fit on one row.

```
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Seg. | NetPDiff | S1_C | S2_C | S3_C | S4_C | S5_C | Total |
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| S1   |      123 |    0 |  186 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   186 |
| S2   |      272 |  442 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   442 |
| S3   |       68 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   99 |    99 |
| S4   |       74 |    0 |    0 |   99 |    0 |    0 |    99 |
| S5   |       66 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  145 |    0 |   145 |
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Okay, hopefully I haven't lost you yet. Now, below, I will post the calculated field I am using in my dashboarding tool just to show you the application for this query:

```
100*(sum(Net_Promotor_Diff)/sum(Total_Count))
```

Like I said, I have this working perfectly fine for the "Segment" filter. What I want to do is be able to calculate that NPS field with multiple filters over it, for example: what is the NPS where respondents are Millenial Males part of Segment 1?

Any suggestions or advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. If I had to guess, this original query and table probably won't work for what I am trying to do in the end since it doesn't allow for multi-dimensional rollups.

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here, the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: check [HyperLogLog++ Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions) - I feel it should be relevant for your case